# Using Beyond Compare 3, how do I generate a report comparing two given folders and showing how many lines were changed in each files using a script

Tags: scripting, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Using a .cmd files that calls a .txt file to generate a txt report.  Trying to do a folder compare but that keeps coming up blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **file-report** scripting command.

```
load c:\folder1 c:\folder2
expand all
select all.files
file-report layout:summary output-to:c:\out.txt
```

To run the script, use the command line:

```
bcompare.exe @c:\script.txt
```

References:

[Beyond Compare Help - Scripts](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?scripts.html)

[Beyond Compare Help - Scripting Reference](http://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/index.html?scripting_reference.html)

Comment: ah. I was doing a folder report.  I didn't realize file report could also take a folder.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I'll see how it looks with all the different options on.